# Excel - count days in each month between two dates (both dates available)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have found the solution thought it would be good to share:

so the formula should be :
=((MAX(CT$6-$N8,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(CT$6,-1)-$N8,0))-(MAX(CT$6-$O8,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(CT$6,-1)-$O8,0))+(EOMONTH(CT$6,0)=EOMONTH($N8,0)))*1

:)

I am trying to write an excel formula which can be dragged across a row of cells to give the number of days in each month between two specified dates. E.g:

[image]

I tried using a if with sum product formula from the same website but for some reason it is not recognising the days of last month. was wondering if someone could help explain what this formula does and how to correct it.

=IFERROR(IF(AND(CS$6>=$M9,CS$6<=$N9),SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT($M9&":"&IF($N9="",TODAY(),$N9))))=MONTH(CS$6))),),"")

Comment: BTW INDIRECT is volatile and overusing it will cause poor user experience.  You can change it to: `=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,$A2):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,$B2)),"mmm")=C$1)),"")` to avoid the volatility.

Comment: something is not right here.  with the start date in 2021 and the end date in 2022 I get `31`,`47`,`46`,`30` which is correct as it goes over a full year.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I am calculating the rent per month based on a date rate , so I kind of need it to take  the years in to consideration.  is that possible?

Comment: you would need to add the year to the title ie: Jan 2021 and so forth then change the text output format to `mmm yyyy`

Comment: thanks Scott, sorry what is the $ZZ:$ZZ  part in the index column actually suppose to be

Comment: I just use a column at random here.  It does not matter what column is used, as we care about the row number.  I use zz because it most likely is not being used and will not cause a recalc when it does not matter what is in those cells.

Comment: thank you but it is still not working :( . it doesn't show me any days  at all. basically an error (-)

Comment: Submit to the likelihood that there will not be a simple neat little soln. - (surprisingly so as at first it doesn't really seem like a significant feat) -what I have below should suit your needs but is relatively complex (albeit robust & accurate - thanks to some feedback you provided).

Comment: @Charlotte Sarah Smith - do you mind reverting to updated soln (which required addition of just 1 day btw) below pls?  Ta

Comment: @Charlotte-- your example in the table above - are you sure Feb is meant to have 19 days (has this question come up prev and you've already addressed? :)

Comment: Hi , yes basically I need to calculated the rent based on the days of stay.  so according to my calculations feb should be 19 days :) . the formula I originally had (IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & $B2)),"mmm")=C$1)),"") works fine if my end date is the end of that month , it does recognise lets say 17/05/2021  has 17 days in may , but would recognise the days of may if the date was 31/05/2021 which I find very strange :I

Comment: @Charlotte - see updated formula / workbooks / links - I've put in what I understand you wanted all along- and have have recommended a potential approach to slimming your workbook down significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SECOND REVISION (R2)***

- Updated workbook link to capture fixed column headings
- Eqn / formula also includes static view

Depending upon years spanned, R2 represents a less favourable outcome re space (will require more columns).  In this case, number of additional columns required to match stacked view ~100 (!!).

**FIRST REVISION (R1) etc.** **based upon @Charlotte.Sarah.Smith feedback**

- Days in each month were 1 day less than they should have been - **this has been** **corrected** (in both screenshot, linked sheet, and relevant eqns)
- **Also showcase** a couple of sample illustrations/visual representations which may/not be of interest (included within linked sheet too)

---

Suppose we wanted to expand upon @Will's solution by *stacking* the dates by *year*, so that column headings can vary according to different start dates (as opposed to the very first start date that happens to appear)...

For instance, if the next row included the date range 'start = 10/02/16' through 'end = 15/03/19' - you'll appreciate that the number of columns spanning Jan-Dec ('16), Jan-Dec ('17),... up to (and incl.) the range in the first row (Jan '21 - Mar '23) becomes unwieldy.

---

By using a *data table* (see [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j962rSPM1iQDqvDXz4?e=JR0bzv)) you can produce a 'stacked' view of the number of days per month regardless of the year (!) - see screenshot below and link to [this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j963vUpGKbdvBUJbFG?e=GHDNkN) *[updated/corrected]* worksheet.

[image: R1,stacked days by month chart]

***R2 screenshot:***

[image: R2 - Update]

---

**REVISION**

*See validation/reconciliation column at end*

*Visual representations - could be useful for assessing trends etc.

[image: 2D and 3D illustrations]

---

***Fun in 3D too!***

[image]

1] Red font: first row that defines the construct of the data table: enter date range in the format '10/02/2021-15/08/2023'

Cell E3 eqn (drag to right):

```
=IFERROR(IF($A3>EDATE(E$2,1),0,MAX(,IFERROR(IF(MIN($B3,MIN(EDATE(E$2,1),$B3))=E$2-1,0,MIN($B3,MIN(EDATE(E$2,1),$B3))),"")-MAX($A3,E$2))),0)
```

*(Similar to what we've seen previously)*

2] Table below red font: enter any start date (as a regular date, e.g. dd/mm/yyyy) < end date (likewise, regular date) in columns A, B as desired/req.

---

**Data Table**

3] Data Table (column data): enter the following in cell c4 (drag down as req.)

```
=TEXT(A4,"dd/mm/yyyy")&"-"&TEXT(B4,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

4] Data Table (highlight cells c3:d42, insert data table, select blank/empty cell for 'row input' and c2 for 'column input')

*The data table should 'come to life' (calculate sheet, shift + F9) otherwise.*

**FilterXML**

5] Split result by delimiter '|' using FilterXML as follows (cell E4, only drag down, not to right):

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<AllText><Num>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(D4,2,LEN(D4)-1),LEN(MID(D4,2,LEN(D4)-1))-1),"|","</Num><Num>")&"</Num></AllText>","//Num")),"")
```

**VALIDATION**

Note the check column: date difference = sum of days in table (default cell colour is otherwise RED):

[image: Check column included as part of revised / corrected solution - all in order ☺]

***REVISION 2***

Here is the formula for a static version of above (i.e. no stacking by year, instead, each date in column headers are distinct re calcs) - it was already available in row with red font(!!)

```
=IFERROR(IF($A3>EDATE(C$2,1),0,MAX(,IFERROR(IF(MIN($B3,MIN(EDATE(C$2,1),$B3))=C$2-1,0,MIN($B3,MIN(EDATE(C$2,1),$B3))),"")-MAX($A3,C$2))),0)
```

Viola!

Comment: Hi James, Thank you , but this formula is not showing the right amount of days in the month  it is showing feb has 27 days :(, I have changed my month columns  format to "MMM-YY "" ,

Comment: Yep - out by one day, have corrected, re-uploaded and have included a few interesting graphs for monitoring  / gaining insight re trends etc. depending upon the application/purpose.  Thanks for pointing out @Charlotte

Comment: @Charlotte : any updates in this regard? Can you review/revert/comment pls? Ta

Comment: Hi JB, when you say you have updated it you mean this formula right? =IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<AllText><Num>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(D4,2,LEN(D4)-1),LEN(MID(D4,2,LEN(D4)-1))-1),"|","</Num><Num>")&"</Num></AllText>","//Num")),"") . this fprumua still had column C and D in it , I don't want those columns . my file is too bid and has too much data, I really cant add 2 columns , my original formula works and I get  the exact day for each month except the last month in that date and I was wondering if there is something wrong with my formula :(

Comment: IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & $B2)),"mmm")=C$1)),""). thanks

Comment: Alright - it'll be tough to achieve the 'stacked year approach' I've used with no helper column.  I hear you that's its big and so my approach is prob. not the best as data tables can be heavy.  PS-  the formula you've provided above in the comment - is that all you're looking to fix?  If so, I can slim my soln right down to address directly....

Comment: @Charlotte - np.  FYI - pause for moment to consider your setup/worbook- you say it's quite big with lot's of columns; depending on your range of dates, approach you're taking may require a significant number of additional columns (could be over 25, 50, could be over 100 even, e.g. if your years span > 10) vs mine (nevermind just 2!).

Comment: @Charlotte - np.  FYI - pause for moment to consider your setup/workbook- you say it's quite big with lot's of columns; depending on your range of dates, approach you're taking may require a significant number of additional columns (could be over 25, 50, could be over 100 even, e.g. if your years span > 10) vs mine (nevermind just 2!).

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution would be to compare dates using the MIN and MAX functions like this:

```
=IF(MIN($B2+1,D$1)-MAX($A2,C$1)<0,"",MIN($B2+1,D$1)-MAX($A2,C$1))
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tqmC.png)

This solution uses month starting dates (e.g., Feb 1, 2021), but it could be adapted to work with month end dates instead (e.g., Feb 28, 2021).

The idea is that you take the later of the finish date or month end date minus the lesser of the start date or the month start date.  For the first month and last months, this returns the number of days within that range inclusive of the first and last day.  For all the months between the first and last months, it returns the number of days in the month.

The +1 on the minimum of the end dates seems a little counterintuitive, but it's necessary to include the first and last day in the count.  Without it, you'd get 14 days in March 2022 instead of 15.

The "if less than zero" function makes it return a blank (or zero if you'd prefer) for any month outside the dat range.

This solution does not summarize by month (e.g., 19 days for Feb 2021 plus 28 days for 2022 to get 47 total days in February), but that's consistent with the sample you provided.  The comments also indicate that you want to consider the years as well.

Comment: hi will ,thanks but I don't want to  use additional C  and D columns I need formula like the sum product one that I can used with the data I have without adding additional columns . My file is already overloaded with data and formulas . :D

Comment: Hi, Charlotte!  I totally understand overloaded spreadsheets and have the same problem often enough.  This solution does not require any additional columns.  I just widened out column C in the screenshot so that you could see the whole formula.  I referenced the date in column D (one month to the right) to get the month end date because it simplifies the formula a little bit over adding an EOMONTH().  Either would work though.  The only change this solution requires would be to replace the text month names with a date (1st of each of month).

Comment: Hi Will,  but you have Column D and C in you formula, =IF(MIN($B2+1,D$1)-MAX($A2,C$1)<0,"",MIN($B2+1,D$1)-MAX($A2,C$1)), I dont have those Colomuns and i really cant add them, my file is showing 200 property rentals based on 2 years

Comment: I'm just generically referencing the first and second months.  Since you didn't provide row or column numbers in your screenshot, I assumed the "Start Date" is in A1 which makes the first two months columns C and D.  With the absolute references, you could drag those formulas across an unlimited number of years to the right.

Comment: @user:16199131thanks Will so the formula  works fine till we again reach the end of the months and now it shows 1 day in may and no days in June, I have edited my query to the original file I am using  for better understanding , I need calculate the days of within each month for rental purposes

Comment: Yes, with this approach, you'll need to have the month columns extend at least one month past the last end date (e.g., if the last end date is May 10, 2023, you'll need to have a column for June 2024).  Alternatively, you could modify the formula so that it only references the current month instead of looking one month to the right, but that gets a little uglier because you have to throw in an EOMONTH()+1 to catch the last day of each month instead of just looking at the first day of the next month.